# Unable to create StatusBar in Visual C++ express 2010 using plain win32 api

Tags: winapi, visual-c++-2010

I am using plain Win32 API (no MFC I mean) to create a simple app. I use `CreateWindowEx` with `STATUSCLASSNAME` as specified in MSDN but the handle returned is `NULL`. I made a call to `InitCommonControlsEx` as indicated but that returns `FALSE`! So I suspect that's the reason why the bar isn't created. What's going on? Please help.

I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

```
hStatusBar = ::CreateWindowExW(
  0,
  L"STATUSCLASSNAME",
  L"",
  WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
  0,0,0,0, hWnd, 0, hInstance, NULL
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one simple mistake in your code. `STATUSCLASSNAME` is not a value this is a constant from `< commctrl.h >`. So you code actually should looks like this:

```
 #include <commctrl.h>
 .
 .
 .
 hStatusBar = ::CreateWindowExW(
 0,
 STATUSCLASSNAME,
 L"",
 WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
 0,0,0,0, hWnd, 0, hInstance, NULL
);
```

I suppose you was looking into this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775491%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#STATUSCLASSNAME but as it specified, there are constants in the left column not values

Comment: Oh WOW, that was embarrassing !! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using W (wide) chars and functions you have to change constant name (see inside  `commcrtl.h`). I used:

```
status = CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAMEW,
    L"Spec.chars fine - Czech=Česky", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
    0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and is seems to be ok.